# CanActivate don't display the desired component when the returned result is true

Tags: angular, routes, angular6, canactivate

I have the following API function:

```
checkLoggedInAdmin():boolean
  {
    //Get the JWT token from local storage
    let jwt = localStorage.getItem('jwt');
    let httpParams = new HttpParams().set('jwt', jwt);
    let headerOptions = new HttpHeaders();
    headerOptions.append('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8');
    if(jwt=="" || jwt!=null)
    {
      this.http.post('http://dev.local/scripts/checkLoginAdmin.php', httpParams, {
        headers: headerOptions
      }).subscribe(
        (data)=>{
          if(data==true){
            return this.loggedIn = true;
          }
          else{
            return this.loggedIn = false;
          }
        },
        (error)=>{
          console.log(error)
        }

      )
    }
    else
    {
      this.loggedIn = false;
      return this.loggedIn;
    }
  }
```

This function, will check if a JWT exists, then if the user logged in is an admin, to let him navigate through different component.

The following, is the canActivate method. I created a new service for it, and include it at the app.module.ts:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { CanActivate, ActivatedRouteSnapshot, RouterStateSnapshot, Router } from '@angular/router';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { AuthApiService } from './auth-api.service';
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AuthGuardService implements CanActivate {

  constructor(private router: Router, private authApi: AuthApiService) { }

  canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, 
    state: RouterStateSnapshot) :boolean
  { 
    if(this.authApi.checkLoggedInAdmin()==true)
    {
      return true;
    }
    else
    {
      //return false;
      this.router.navigate(['/login'])
    }
  }


}
```

The PHP is returning true when the user logging in is an admin, and false if it's not the case, but the their is no redirection, to the component called `forgot` if it is true. And even no redirection when it is false to `login` component.

Here is my routes:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { LoginComponent } from './login/login.component';
import { ForgotPasswordComponent } from './forgot-password/forgot-password.component';
import { AuthGuardService } from './auth-guard.service';

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'login',
    component: LoginComponent
  },
  {
    path:'',
    component: LoginComponent
  },

  {
    path: 'forgot',
    component: ForgotPasswordComponent,
    canActivate: [AuthGuardService]
  },
  {
    path: '**',
    redirectTo: 'login',
    pathMatch: 'full'
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

Comment: `checkLoggedInAdmin()` is asynchronous, so `this.authApi.checkLoggedInAdmin()==true` isn't going to work

Comment: This was a test. It was `if(this.authApi.checkLoggedInAdmin())` so return true

Comment: Okay, but my point is that `checkLoggedInAdmin` function never returns true. It is asynchronous, and you're trying to return within the `subscribe` function

Comment: Okay. So what should I do sir ?

Comment: Which version of RXJS are you using?

Comment: It is the last one.

Comment: Okay, I based my answer below on RXJS 6 (the newest one), so hopefully that should work for you.

Answer (score 0):

Change the `checkLoggedInAdmin` function to return an Observable.

Here we're using map to transform the result, so you'll need to add the following imports as well:

```
import { map, tap } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { of, Observable } from 'rxjs';

  checkLoggedInAdmin():Observable<boolean>
  {
    //Get the JWT token from local storage
    let jwt = localStorage.getItem('jwt');
    let httpParams = new HttpParams().set('jwt', jwt);
    let headerOptions = new HttpHeaders();
    headerOptions.append('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8');
    if(jwt=="" || jwt!=null)
    {
      this.http.post('http://dev.local/scripts/checkLoginAdmin.php', httpParams, {
        headers: headerOptions
      }).pipe(
         tap(data => this.loggedIn = (data == true)),
         map(data => this.loggedIn)
      );
    }
    else
    {
      this.loggedIn = false;
      return of(false);
    }
  }
```

Then, simply modify the `canActivate` to return the observable

```
canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot) :Observable<boolean>
{
    return this.authApi.checkLoggedInAdmin();
}
```

Comment: @droidnation in what way? Are you getting an error, or is the behaviour not what you expected?

Comment: I made a method to chekc the status of the variable `loggedIn` and it returned `undefined` even when user is logged in, so when I am setting it as true, it's not saving it, and can't know why.

Comment: Change the `map` function to set `this.loggedIn` before it returns `data == true`

Comment: can you edit your answer for it. I think I am unable to access the variable and change it. Even though it was set at the beginning of the class.

Comment: @droidnation Try that. Please note that there is a new import there for `tap`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176105/discussion-between-user184994-and-droidnation).